# How to organize imports in a Scala project?

Tags: scala, import

Suppose my project has package `org.abc` with several Scala files inside. All the Scala files contain *the same* `import` statements, e.g. `import org.x._`, `import org.y._`, `import org.z._`

I don't like the repetition. Can I move all these `import` statements to one single file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the same pattern that is used in [scala/package.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/package.scala): create an `org.abc` `package object` with a `type` and a `val` for each definitions you want to import from `org.{x, y, z}._`:

```
package org

package object abc {
  type Maybe[A] = org.x.Maybe[A]
  val Maybe = org.x.Maybe
  type MyClass = org.y.MyClass
  val MyClass = org.y.MyClass
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, by using [package objects](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html)